# Does contextloaderlistener has visibility over MVC configuration in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on spring security. I have added tag-> global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" in security.xml to enable @PreAuthorize annotations. Do I need to add this in spirngmvc-config.xml file too? does contextloaderlistener has visibility over MVC configuration?

Comment: The best approach to understand these would be to have a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

contextloaderlistener does not have visibility over MVC configuration. You need to add global-method-security tag in mvc configuration file too.